# jqplot pie chart yii extension not showing datalabels

Tags: php, jqplot, yii-extensions

I am able to render the pie chart using yii extension. However, I am unable to see data labels.

Usually, jqplot would get the data labels by default if using javascript. However, I need to show the data labels using yii extension.

Any idea how I could pass data labels to show using the yii extension?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that replacing the files in the extensions assets folder and plugins folder, I could resolve the problem.

I replaced jquery.jqplot.js and jqplot.pieRenderer.js from www.jqplot.com downloaded jquery.jqplot.1.0.8r1250.zip

Hope this helps someone else.